# Gaussian processes for large data

Tags: tensorflow, gpflow, gaussian-process

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this code? I have installed `gpflow` on an M1 Mac and I am learning Gaussian process (GP) regression. I was trying to run this script found [here](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/750f351fe696ab6ba41ed444728f444a20d312d1/doc/sphinx/notebooks/advanced/gps_for_big_data.pct.py) but keep getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/amninder/Project/04_machinelearning.ipynb Cell 68 in <cell line: 37>()
     31 # %% [markdown]
     32 # Now we run the optimization loop for 20,000 iterations.
     33 
     34 # %%
     35 maxiter = reduce_in_tests(20000)
---> 37 logf = run_adam(m, maxiter)
     38 plt.plot(np.arange(maxiter)[::10], logf)
     39 plt.xlabel("iteration")

/Users/amninder/Project/04_machinelearning.ipynb Cell 68 in run_adam(model, iterations)
     21     optimizer.minimize(training_loss, model.trainable_variables)
     23 for step in range(iterations):
---> 24     optimization_step()
     25     if step % 10 == 0:
     26         elbo = -training_loss().numpy()

File ~/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb
...
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]

     [[{{node Adam/Adam/update/ResourceApplyAdam}}]] [Op:__inference_optimization_step_6942]
```

My goal is to implement GP on a multivariate dataset. If someone could share any suggestions on how to adapt this script for my use case, that would be great!

Comment: This is not an error message, is just an incomplete part of a traceback and does not say anything, include the whole traceback.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I have edited the question to include the entire message

Comment: I feel like you're still missing something in the error message. Are you sure that's all of it?
Also, which versions of Python, Tensoflow, and GPflow are you using?

Comment: I ran the same script as in the [link](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/750f351fe696ab6ba41ed444728f444a20d312d1/doc/sphinx/notebooks/advanced/gps_for_big_data.pct.py) but get the error. Not sure if it has to do with M1 mac since gpflow is still under development for M1. TensorFlow version: 2.9.2, Gpflow: 2.5.2, Python; 3.9.13

Comment: Update: I ran it on a Windows machine, and it works fine.